# magento meta description not showing correctly

Tags: magento-1.9, seo, meta-tags

I am using magento 1.9 and I am having issues with the Meta Descrioptions not appearing correctly in Google results.

the homepage source it has this:

```
 <meta name="description" content="Maximise the aesthetic appeal and functionality of your retail business with our quality shop fittings. Browse our online range today." />
```

but the Google results look like:

```
www.mysite.com/
Banner1. Banner2. Banner3. Shopings & delivering direct from the importers!! All prices are PLUS G.S.T. Buy Direct & save today!! close. Banner1 ...
```

these banner1,banner2,banner3 are banner names given to the ecsso easybanner slider installed in the site .i want to display meta description instead of these contents.can any one suggest?

Answer (score 0):

Google does not always take the Meta Description you give them. It chooses itself according to its algorithm.

What you could do is:

- Ask Google to Re-Index Your Site
- Rethink Your Meta Description
- Don’t Duplicate Your Meta Descriptions

The source is old but this still applies
Source: [Moz Blog](https://moz.com/blog/why-wont-google-use-my-meta-description)